# Drag&drop в C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-n-drop

Реально ли реализовать в WinForms:

Например: есть 2 `datagridview`, в одном список авто, в другом список заказов, чтобы можно было мышкой перетянуть из `datagridview2` с заказами один или несколько заказов на один из автомобилей в `datagridview1`, и после перетаскивания сделали `insert` в бд согласно выполненных действий,

или, например: в таблице заказов до перетаскивания поле `id_truck` было пустое, после перетаскивания, `update` и вставили `id` авто, на которое кинули заказ. Реально ли такое?

Comment: реально, а почему нет. Обрабатываете соответствующие события и делаете. Что уже пробовали?

Comment: @rdorn спасибо большое что откликнулись, я все сделал, все получилось. Вы случайно не работали с DataGridViewAutoFilter?

Comment: к сожалению не доводилось. добавьте свое решение в качестве ответа, мой комментарий хоть и принес пользу, не настолько информативен, чтобы вставлять его в ответ